# Excel , how to insert separator for multi line in single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple line in a cell and I need to add commma or semi colon after word for each line to display like AA; BB; CC; DD;
it's possible to do that?

[image]

Comment: do you still want the line breaks or just the `; `

Comment: I don't know how diference , but I think just ; after the line is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"; ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this simple version of SUBSTITUTE:*

[image]

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",",")
```